# Find principal DNF and CNF of $Q\land(P\lor \neg Q)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find principal DNF and CNF of $Q\land(P\lor \neg Q)$.

[My attempt:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZwXb.jpg)
\begin{align}
Q\land(P\lor \neg Q)
  &\implies (Q\land P) \lor (Q\land \neg Q) \\
  &\implies (Q\land P) \lor \mathrm{F} \\
  &\implies Q\land P.
\end{align}

Comment: I've edited your question so that it can be more easily read (without having to load an image).  Can you please check to make sure that I haven't broken anything or changed the intent of your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is the PDNF of the expression.... well done!

To get the PCNF, note that $Q = (Q \lor P) \land (Q \lor \neg P)$